# read pdf document properties from terminal as seen in nautilus

Tags: command-line, pdf, metadata

From the terminal I would like to be access the data that is readable when right clicking on a pdf file and selecting "document". [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwerL.png)

I have tried reading metadata with tools such as mminfo and pdftk but some files are password protected so they can't show me the meta data.

Help appreciated.

Comment: [Crossposting on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675776/read-pdf-document-properties-from-terminal-as-seen-in-nautilus#comment13853958_10675776)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What version?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the program `pdfinfo` from the package `poppler-utils`. For font information you can use `pdffonts` from the same package.